# Backbone Global Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, backbone.js, global

How can I use a global variable in Backbone at this case? The problem is that I have more than 120 views like `HomeView`, and it will be too hard to define the same `polyglot` var in all views. Is there another way?

```
var TranslatetView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    window.polyglot = new Polyglot({phrases:{'hello':'hello'}});
    var polyglot    = window.polyglot.phrases;
});

var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    console.log(polyglot.hello);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to mention that Global variables are bad. Try to limit yourself to as few of them as possible. Global namespace pollution is very dangerous and can cause unexpected errors in the future.

A technique I often use to get around the issue of polluting the global namespace is by creating your own namespace.

For example, you can do something like

```
window.myNamespace = window.myNameSpace || {};
window.myNamespace.TranslateView = ...;
window.myNamespace.HomeView = ...;
```

If HomeView and TranslateView belong to different modules, you can also namespace those.

```
window.myNamespace.TransteModule = {};
window.myNamespace.TransteModule.TranslateView = ....;
```

This way you only create 1 global variable for your namespace. You also get the benefit of easily identifying the view by its containing module.